How can I debug a Xubuntu machine that reboots after several minutes, even if running from installer ISO?
I have been using this machine successfully, with Xubuntu, as my main machine, for 18 months.
It is dual-boot.
Under Windows I have zero problems; it works 24/7.
Under Xubuntu the machine reboots spontaneously after a few minutes of use.
This is true even if I boot up the machine from a Xubuntu 22.04 USB drive!!
I have tried with Xubuntu 24.04.01 as well as the original 22.04.2 ISO from when I first commissioned the machine.
I can log in and make SSH connections but it never works long enough for me to SCP a log file to another machine.
A hardware fault seems like the obvious answer, but Windows works perfectly happily.
Is it possible Xubuntu accesses a defective bit of hardware that Windows does not?
I would be grateful for any hints about how to track this down.
                         - o 0 o -


Processor : AMD Ryzen 9 6900HX with Radeon Graphics 3.30 GHz
Installed RAM : 64.0 GB


You do realize the two Xubuntu ISOs you mention use different installers; the 22.04 ISOs used ubiquity and 24.04 used ubuntu-desktop-installer for Xubuntu; this means the installer logs are in different locations, but machine logs are still just machine logs

Yes, it is possible that Xubuntu accesses a defective bit of hardware that Windows does not. One thing to test is the RAM: You can use memtest. See this link. You can run the memory test overnight, and there should be no error at all logged (and no automatic shutdown). There could also be problems with some other hardware, maybe some overheating problem or a crack that opens due to increased temperature or maybe a problem due to failing power supply (too low voltage).

Linux using hardware differently; e.g. a cooling fan not running, allowing a (important) component to overheat?  Add an external fan for cooling to see if it might help?

@guiverc I was unaware of that difference, but I was only booting up with those in order to see the machine logs.  I never expected to be able to view their log of why they crashed.

@sudodus These are the great suggestions I was hoping for. Thank you!  I did, by the way, remove and reinsert all connectors and circuits, but it made no difference

@Hannu Yes. That is definitely worth trying.

@sudodus, Fwiw -- memtest booted from USB showed zero defects. :-(  Next step is to  use an external fan to blow cold air into the thing.
